# How do email verifying services work and how do to it?

Tags: c#, .net, verification

I'm just talking in general terms how do Email Verifying Services Work and how they don't need to send emails to verify a mail box exists

My question arises because I tried programming my own email verification tool but on the connecting to the domain it always fails to connect.

Comment: In my experience, the answer is "not very well". Lots of false positives *and* false negatives.

Comment: Maybe you could expand on the 'failure to connect' and we could help you there

Comment: Im writing the current verification method in C# .net but it should be straight forward
First I obtained the MX Records of the domain and selected the exchange domain with the lowest preference amongst the domains (im using gmail.com so there are multiple exchange domains).

TcpClient s = new TcpClient();
s.Connect("gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com", 25);

But I get this exception when trying to connect:

Comment: System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: 'A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond 172.217.197.27:25'